Magento REST API - Order Search with Date Filters Returns Signature Invalid
I'm trying to filter orders by date using the Magento REST API (/rest/V1/orders). I want to get orders from a given date range.
The API works perfectly fine with basic search criteria (without filters), but throws a signature invalid error when I add date filters.
Here's what works (returns orders successfully):
$searchCriteriaArray = [
    'searchCriteria' => [
        'currentPage' => 1,
        'pageSize' => 10
    ]
];

I've tried the following approaches to add date filters, but all result in a signature invalid error:
Using filterGroups with condition_type:
$searchCriteriaArray = [
    'searchCriteria' => [
        'currentPage' => 1,
        'pageSize' => 10,
        'filterGroups' => [
            0 => [
                'filters' => [
                    0 => [
                        'field' => 'created_at',
                        'value' => '2024-01-01',
                        'condition_type' => 'gteq'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

Using camelCase conditionType:
$searchCriteriaArray = [
    'searchCriteria' => [
        'filterGroups' => [
            0 => [
                'filters' => [
                    0 => [
                        'field' => 'created_at',
                        'value' => '2024-01-01',
                        'conditionType' => 'gteq'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'currentPage' => 1,
        'pageSize' => 10
    ]
];

Using flat structure:
$searchCriteriaArray = [
    'searchCriteria[currentPage]' => 1,
    'searchCriteria[pageSize]' => 10,
    'searchCriteria[filter][0][field]' => 'created_at',
    'searchCriteria[filter][0][value]' => '2024-01-01',
    'searchCriteria[filter][0][condition_type]' => 'gteq'
];

I'm encoding the parameters using this code:
$baseUrl = 'https://mydomain.com';
$endpoint = '/rest/V1/orders';
$queryString = http_build_query($searchCriteriaArray);
$url = $baseUrl . $endpoint . '?' . $queryString;
// oAuth code

All attempts with filters result in:
{"message":"The signature is invalid. Verify and try again."}

I've tried:

Different date formats (with/without time)
Different condition types (gt, gteq, from, after)
Different array structures
Different field names (created_at, updated_at)

Has anyone successfully implemented date filtering with the orders API? What am I missing?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Filters are working with below code please try :
<?php

// Magento Base URL and Access Token
$baseUrl = 'Store Url'; // Replace with your Magento base URL
$accessToken = 'Access token';

// Define the date range and pagination parameters
$fromDate = '2024-05-20 00:00:00'; // Start date
$toDate = '2024-12-22 00:00:00';   // End date
$pageSize = 10;                    // Number of results per page
$currentPage = 1;                  // Current page number

// Build the search criteria query string without the status filter
$queryString = http_build_query([
    'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]' => 'created_at',
    'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]' => 'from',
    'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]' => $fromDate,
    'searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]' => 'created_at',
    'searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]' => 'to',
    'searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]' => $toDate,
    'searchCriteria[currentPage]' => $currentPage,
    'searchCriteria[pageSize]' => $pageSize,
]);

// Initialize cURL
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseUrl . '/rest/V1/orders?' . $queryString);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
]);

// Execute the API call
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for errors
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'cURL Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}

curl_close($ch);

// Parse and display the response
if ($response) {
    $orders = json_decode($response, true);
    if (isset($orders['items'])) {
        echo "Filtered Orders:\n";
        foreach ($orders['items'] as $order) {
            echo "Order ID: " . $order['entity_id'] . "\n";
            echo "Status: " . $order['status'] . "\n";
            echo "Created At: " . $order['created_at'] . "\n";
            echo "Total: " . $order['grand_total'] . "\n";
            echo "------------------------\n";
        }
    } else {
        echo "No orders found for the given criteria.\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "Error fetching orders from the Magento API.\n";
}


Thank you so much. It worked.
